# Build Failure When Running Through Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting the below error when running through Jenkins. Please help me to resolve this.

```
Started by an SCM change Building in workspace
> C:\Users\xxxx\.jenkins\jobs\GITMavenJenkins\workspace
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Tharvez/WebDriverMaven.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Tharvez/WebDriverMaven.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 1a92ef90881699bc930d65972afb424bc25c1fad (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 1a92ef90881699bc930d65972afb424bc25c1fad
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list 466b6f470e5784434b5b2e25cce577a452b5b7c0 # timeout=10
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"mvn.bat clean package && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
'mvn.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Please declare your Maven installation in the global configuration (my Jenkins is running on Linux):

[image]

And please use this Maven version in your Jenkins jobs, it should solve your pb:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It fails to find **mvn.bat** script file.
It depends how you run maven.
is it in 'execute shell' step by running **mvn.bat**? If so, then it looks for the file in the machine **PATH**.

Comment: When i run the script directly through Maven it is executing. By running MVN Package in the command prompt it executes the scripts.

Comment: Running in Jenkins in 'Execute shell' step is different from running in command prompt because in Jenkins it runs as Jenkins user and it has a different environment that may not have the mvn.bat in the PATH